# Write under the graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Please, can anyone help me to write under the graph in LaTeX like this graph:

[image]

this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=4em, row sep=9ex, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=8pt] (M) { & &\node[mypoint, label={above:v$_{3}$}] (V3) {};
&  & & \node[mypoint, label={above:v$_{3}$}] (V31) {};\\
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{1}$}] (V1) {}; 
    & & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{4}$}] (V4) {};
  & \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=-6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{1}$}] (V11) {};
   & & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{4}$}] (V41) {};
    \\
    \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=2pt,yshift=4pt]v$_{2}$}] (V2) {}; & & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{5}$}] (V5) {};
    & \node[mypoint, label={[left,xshift=2pt,yshift=4pt]v$_{2}$}] (V21) {}; & & \node[mypoint, label={[right,xshift=6pt,yshift=-3pt]v$_{5}$}] (V51) {};\\
};
\draw (V3) --  (V1);
\draw (V1) --  (V4);
\draw (V2) --(V5);
\draw (V11) --  (V31);
\draw (V11) --  (V41);
\draw (V11) --  (V51);

\draw (V21) --  (V41);
\draw (V21) --  (V31);
\draw (V21) --(V51);


\end{tikzpicture} 

    \caption{A bipartite graph \label{19}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

For the edge connecting the two nodes, use the `node` command to get what you want:

`\draw (V2) to node[below] {$G$} (V5);`

`\draw (V21) to node[below] {$K_{2,3}$} (V51);`

If that is too close to the edge, use `below=5pt` (or some other size) to move it farther below.

Comment: Ok, but if you don't have an edge between v2 and v5 for example in figure one

Comment: Put `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in the header, and write `\node at ($(V2)!.5!(V5)+(270:.5)$) {$G$};`. This will place a node "G" a distance of .5 below the halfway point between V2 and V5.

Comment: @MaryamFasfous An alternative to  Jānis' suggestion above, is to do `\path (v2) -- node{foo} (v5);`.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

i rewrote your code to more simple and concise form (off-topic):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, quotes} % added tikz libraries

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
             auto = right,
    node distance = 11mm,
    every matrix/.style = {matrix of nodes,
                      nodes={circle, fill,
                             minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm},
                      column sep=4em,
                      row sep=9ex,
                      }
                        ]
\matrix (M1) 
{
                        & |[label=right:$v_3$]|     \\
|[label=left:$v_1$]|    & |[label=right:$v_4$]|     \\
|[label=left:$v_2$]|    & |[label=right:$v_5$]|     \\
};
\draw   (M1-2-1) -- (M1-1-2)
        (M1-2-1) -- (M1-2-2)
        (M1-3-1) to ["$\mathrm{G}$"] (M1-3-2);  % <--
          ]
%
\matrix (M2) [right=of M1]
{
                        & |[label=right:$v_3$]|     \\
|[label=left:$v_1$]|    & |[label=right:$v_4$]|     \\
|[label=left:$v_2$]|    & |[label=right:$v_5$]|     \\
};
\draw   (M2-2-1) -- (M2-1-2)
        (M2-2-1) -- (M2-2-2)
        (M2-2-1) -- (M2-3-2)
        (M2-3-1) -- (M2-1-2)
        (M2-3-1) -- (M2-2-2)
        (M2-3-1) to ["$\mathrm{K}_{2,3}$"] (M2-3-2); % <--
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

addition to your code for which you looking for, is indicated by `% <---`